# Django signals for models value change condition?

Tags: python, django, signals

I have a very simple models in my models.py like this :

```
class Music(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Album(models.Model):
    musician= models.CharField(
        related_name='musician',
        max_length=100
    )

    music = models.ForeignKey(
        Music,
        related_name='music'
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In this case, i made a very simple logic in my signals.py to check if the new field (new music) has just added to album.

```
Album(musician="someone", music=Music.objects.get(title="something")) #pk=1
Album.save()
```

like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Album)
def add_new_album(sender, instance, **kwargs):   
    if kwargs.get('created'):
       print "new album recently created"
```

In other condition, i want to make a signals that only be responded if the existing fields is edited to the new one :

```
edit_album = Album.objects.get(pk=1)
edit_album.music = Music.objects.get(title="something_else")
edit_album.save()
```

The using of post_save receiver make add_new_album() function is triggered every time i edit the existing field.. So my question is, what is the logic that should be implemented in signals.py that only respond the editing fields condition ?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I faced this particular issue recently and I wanted to share my initial solution in case it helps others or even the original poster.  Or better, spurs a discussion to bring a better solution.

I didn't want to use any third party libraries (especially one that had migrations on the DB) and wanted to use the built in signals provided by Django.

My solution is to:

1) Create the function I want to trigger when the particular field has changed (in the questioner's case the music field on the Album instance)

```
def do_this_when_album_music_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    // do something
    print("I'm only going to be called if the field has changed")
```

2) Create the custom signal I want to send when the particular field changes

```
album_music_changed = Signal(providing_args=[])
```

3) Create a pre_save signal receiver that will check whether or not the field has changed and "connect" the custom signal to the receiver, otherwise "disconnect" it

```
@receiver(signal=signal=models.signals.pre_save, sender=Album)
def album_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    old_album = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    if not old_album.music == instance.music:
        album_music_changed.connect(do_this_when_album_music_changed, sender=Album)
    else:
        album_music_changed.disconnect(do_this_when_album_music_changed, sender=Album)
```

4) Finally add a post_save signal that will actually send the trigger to call the custom signal and hence the function you want to run

```
@receiver(signal=signal=models.signals.post_save, sender=Album)
def album_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    album_music_changed.send(sender=sender)
```

In my case, I needed to have the function run after post_save of the instance so this was the best thing I could come up with, if anyone has a better solution that would be awesome if you could share it.

Of course if you don't need the triggered function to run post_save and you are happy to run it pre_save you can just call the .send() inside the first "if" block and not have to worry about the post_save receiver

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

So I you want to trigger your signal only when certain field is changed right?
You can use a package called [Django Field history](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-field-history)

Something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=<sender>, dispatch_uid=<string>)
def method(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    last_field_change = FieldHistory.objects.filter(field_name=<your_field_which_you_want_to_check_for_change>,
                                          object_id=instance.id).last()
    if last_field_change:
         #do your thing
```